# Boundary Condition Problem - Diffusion Equation

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

So, in my 1D diffusion equation, everything works as I would expect.

```
    eq = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(p[x, t]\)\) == 
   diffusionrate*Laplacian[p[x, t], {x}];

diffusionrate = 1;

iv = {p[x, 0] == 0, p[0, t] == Sin[t], p[1, t] == 0};

s1D = NDSolve[{eq, iv}, {p[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot3D[p[x, t] /. s1D, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

And gives a nice result

[image]

But when I try to do this in 3D, I expand on the above like so,

```
eq2 = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(p[x, y, z, t]\)\) == 
   diffusionrate*Laplacian[p[x, y, z, t], {x, y, z}];

diffusionrate = 1;

iv = {p[x, y, z, 0] == 0, p[0, 0, 0, t] == Sin[t], p[1, 1, 1, t] == 0};

s3D = NDSolve[{eq2, iv}, {p[x, y, z, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0,
    1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

And I get the error

```
NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition p[0,0,0,t]==Sin[t] is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain.
```

But, I think this is defined along the boundary. I don't understand why it isn't working and why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to specify boundary conditions and initial conditions, for example like so:

```
eq2 = Derivative[0,0,0,1][p][x,y,z,t] == 
   Laplacian[p[x,y,z,t], {x,y,z}];
iv = {p[x, y, z, 0] == 0};
bcs = {p[0, y, z, t] == Sin[t], p[1, y, z, t] == 0};
Dynamic["time: " <> ToString[CForm[currentTime]]]
s3D = NDSolveValue[{eq2, iv, bcs}, 
  p, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}
  , EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;)
  ]
```